# HTML+CSS: Как обернуть ссылкой зафлоаченный элемент?

Tags: html, css

Не вдаваясь в то, зачем это надо: допустим, у нас есть обёрнутая ссылкой картинка, но нам нужно, чтобы зафлоченной (`float:left`) была именно картинка, а не ссылка. Естественно, что картинка выпадет из ссылки. Как это предотвратить?

Ещё раз повторюсь, что в силу причин, в которые мы не будем вдаваться, решение зафлоатить ссылку вместо картинки не подходит (иначе я бы не задавал этого вопроса).

```css
img {
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#">
    <img src="images/image.png" alt="image">
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Не плохо было бы код добавить. Может быть `clearfix` добавить ссылке в которую обернута картинка.

Comment: До не вопрос, только код совершенно очевидный из текста будет...

Comment: А что тогда значит выпадает?

Comment: Означает, что картинка оказывается вне ссылки, а сама ссылка приобретает высоту 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Первый вариант добавить ссылке `display: inline-block;`

```css
img{
    float: left;
    width: 32px;
}
a {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#"> 
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b9ba7c62da59f947cc51e7474a86e4db?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="image"> 
    </a>
</div>
```

Второй вариант добавить класс `.clearfix`

```css
img{
    float: left;
    width: 32px;
}

.clearfix:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#" class="clearfix"> 
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b9ba7c62da59f947cc51e7474a86e4db?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="image"> 
    </a>
</div>
```

Третий вариант добавить ссылке `display: inline-flex;`

```css
img{
    float: left;
    width: 32px;
}

a { display: inline-flex; }
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="#"> 
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/b9ba7c62da59f947cc51e7474a86e4db?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" alt="image"> 
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Отличиный ответ! Спасибо Вам за потраченное время.